# Angular Meteor arrow function in controller declaration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-meteor

I am following [this Angular-Meteor tutorial](http://www.angular-meteor.com/). And there is such code snippet:

```
angular.module('socially').directive('partiesList', function () {

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'parties-list.html',
      controllerAs: 'partiesList',
      controller: function ($scope, $reactive) {
        $reactive(this).attach($scope);

        this.newParty = {};

        this.helpers({
          parties: () => {
            return Parties.find();
          }
        });

        this.addParty = () => {
          Parties.insert(this.newParty);
          this.newParty = {};
        };

        this.removeParty = (party) => {
          Parties.remove({_id: party._id});
        };
      }
    };
  });
```

I am mainly concerned with `() => {}`  syntax. If I use arrow function syntax in controller declaration it does not work:

```
...
controller: ($scope, $reactive) => { //this does not work
            $reactive(this).attach($scope);

            this.newParty = {};

            this.helpers({
              parties: () => {
                return Parties.find();
              }
            });
...
```

Can someone explain me when I can use arrow function and when can not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because arrow functions doesn't create a new `this` context like regular functions but uses the parent's one. 
When defining a controller, it matters, and when defining helpers it does not.
For a more detailed answer you can also look here: https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/issues/965#issuecomment-165916592